# Where is acedao.dll?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to know if Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.dll version 12 is the same thing as acedao.dll. If not where can I find acedao.dll and add a reference to it in a C# WPF project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if the Interop dll is the same as acedao.dll.

Visit [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en) to download the dll as a separate component.

Note though that Jet 4.0, msjet40.dll, is a Windows operating system component and Windows requires it.  It is present in Windows 2000 through to Windows 7.   Whereas the acedao.dll must be installed.  Depending on your overall objective you may find that msjet40.dll works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12\acedao.dll"

Comment: I've been trying to find some documentation on acedao and have failed to find any. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not really. But there are a few usnet groups dealing with access http://groups.google.com/groups/dir?hl=en&sel=usenet%3Dmicrosoft.public.access

Comment: Keep in mind that "C:\Programs Files\Microsoft Office\" could be replaced by any other drive/path. Likewise, if the machine doesn't have Office installed, but just the ACE, I doubt you can count on ACEDAO.DLL being in that location.

Comment: A few Access Usenet groups? msnews.microsoft.com has 28 groups in the microsoft.public.access.* hierarchy, and my news server (newsguy) has more than 40 there. There's also comp.databases.ms-access, the oldest newsgroup devoted to Access on Usenet.

Comment: The thing is that I was told that I could get all the datatypes for MS Access with acedao... The problem is that I have no clue how to use it :S

Comment: In my experience the Access newsgroups are fairly unwelcoming -- hostile, even -- for questions about the Access database engine where the Access UI is not being used.